# Get Intersect Date and Time from DateRange List

Tags: c#, sql

I am having n number of DateRange List (A,B, C...n). All lists has Start and End Date and Time. I want to get the intersect (common) date and time range from these list and generate slots in calender accordingly. For Example:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 15-03-2022 10:45 AM | 16-03-2022 11 AM |
| 16-03-2022 10:30 AM | 17-03-2022 11 AM |
| 16-03-2022 10:45 AM | 19-03-2022 12 PM |

Expected result:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 16-03-2022 10:45 AM | 16-03-2022 11 AM |

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have two date ranges that you want to check for overlap (option 1), or do you mean that you have a singular date and time that you want to check is or isn't contained in one of the ranges (option 2)?

Comment: Can you describe more detail? it's pretty vague

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I have n number of date and time and I want the common datetime among them

Comment: So in your example case, you basically want a single DateTime range that is covered in every provided slot?

Comment: is this correct requirement? 1. Pick Start Date 2. Check in list (Start Date & End Date) 3.  Add Latest Start Date to Temp where Start Date is in Start Date and End Date 4. Add first found End Date where it's same as Start Date

Comment: I am not sure I am following the requirement. Using your example… why would the second "Start Date" date time … “16-03-2022 10:30 AM” … NOT be included in the results?

Comment: Are you trying to find _pairs_ of the inputs which overlap or the common overlap of all the inputs together?  It's hard to see how you would "generate slot(s)" plural, if you wanted to find one common overlap over all N inputs, as I showed in an answer.  But that's what your "expected result" suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking for the overlapping range common to all the input ranges.

That's easily done with:

```
SELECT MAX(xstart) AS xstart, MIN(xend) AS xend
  FROM test
HAVING xstart <= xend
;
```

The maximum start date/time represents the only possible start of the overlapping range.

The minimum end date/time represents the only possible end of the overlapping range.

If the calculated maximum start is less than (or equal to) the minimum end, we have an overlap common to all inputs.

The "equal to" case is just a single date/time in common.  If you don't consider that an overlap, change the logic to:

```
SELECT MAX(xstart) AS xstart, MIN(xend) AS xend
  FROM test
HAVING xstart < xend
;
```

If no overlap common to all is found, 0 rows are returned, instead of 1.

[The fiddle (with MySQL)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5ec964f3bbf5a445f92c00396d91bc1)

The result:

| xstart | xend |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-16 10:45:00 | 2022-03-16 11:00:00 |